# Distribution-valued integrals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, distribution-theory

Is there any way to define a distribution valued integral (in some way analogous to the Bochner integral, e.g.)? The idea comes from the following observation I've heard made in physics and applied math settings, a function $f : \mathbb R \to\mathbb C$ is "just a superposition of deltas", which is just an interesting way of saying:
$$f(x) = \int f(y) \delta(x-y)\ dx$$
or, taking $\tau_y$ to be translation by $y$, perhaps more suggestively:
$$f(\cdot) = \int f(y) \tau_y \delta(\cdot)\ dy,$$
i.e. $f$ is a superposition of deltas at point $y$ weighted $f(y)dy$. Now one can make similar observations with the integral formula for the Fourier and inverse Fourier transforms, taking the function as a superposition of "plane waves" i.e. complex exponentials. It's worth noting that in the first case the integral isn't really and integral and in the second the integral is only sometimes an integral, though that's not too important at the moment.

So inspired by these observations, is there a nice way to make this line of thinking rigorous, where we are really integrating distributions over a measure. For example, is there a sane way of defining integrals of function $X \to \mathcal D'$ or $X \to \mathcal S'$ where $(X,\mathcal M, \mu)$ is a measure space and we take the functions to be measurable (presumably putting the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the codomain)?

E.g. the delta function example is of this form, where we define $F : \mathbb R \to \mathcal S'$ by
$$F(x) = f(x) \tau_x\delta$$
and the Fourier transform is of this form where we define $F : \mathbb R \to \mathcal{S}$ by
$$F(x) = f(x) e^{-2\pi i x \cdot}.$$

One final example is if we gave the $\delta$-mass measure to $\mathbb R$, we should expect that, call it $m$,
$$\int \delta_y\ dm(y) = \delta$$
and more generally for any $F : X \to \mathcal S'$,
$$\int F(y)\ dm(y) = F(0).$$

The examples we have are quite suggestive and I feel like this intuition should be able to be "cashed out" into something rigorous.

Comment: Good question. I think trying to use Bochner's or some other integration theory is not a good idea. The theory of distributions has a great internal coherence and beauty that gets messed up if you make hybrids with other approaches. Instead of thinking of $F$ as a function $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ (i.e., an $F(x,y)$ which is a true function with respect to $x$ but a distribution with respect to $y$), see it as an element of $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^2)$ which is distributional with respect to both variables...

Comment: ...Then the kind of manipulations you want are taken care of by Fubini's Theorem for distributions and the Kernel Theorem. Note that your example has an added twist which is you want to do a partial integration with a test function which is the constant function equal to one, so this needs exploiting that $\delta$ is a compactly supported distribution, i.e., is in $\mathscr{E}'$.

Comment: Perhaps you'll find interesting [these notes on vector-valued distributions](https://www.math.uzh.ch/amann/files/distributions.ps) by Herbert Amann. Their initial purpose was to serve as an initial chapter of the second volume of Amann monograph on evolution equations: now they stand alone as an introduction to the subject.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam That makes sense, thanks.

Comment: The ultimate reference on this kind of stuff is the two long papers by L. Schwartz on vector-valued distributions which discuss contractions of tensors or what LS calls Volterra composition. This is similar to building tensors like $A_{ijk}B_{ilmn}C_{jkp}$ in Einstein notation but where tensors become distributional kernels. The only pedagogical account for LS's papers is indeed the set of lectures by Amann mentioned by Daniele. Unfortunately, he did make it as far as Volterra composition.

Comment: To me, the natural way to define an integral of $f : X \to \mathcal{D}'$ would be to say that $\int f(x)\,dx$ is the distribution $u \in \mathcal{D}'$ that satisfies
$\langle u, \varphi \rangle = \int \langle f(x), \varphi \rangle \, dx$
for all $\varphi \in C^\infty_c.$